# CSS grid cells are not square

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I have a CSS grid. Height & width of this grid are same forming a square. Size of each row & column of grid are one-thirds of the size of the height & width respectively. Which would make all the cells square in shape. But they are not square. They seem like it, they are off. Below is screenshot

[image]

Let me explain the figure:

1. Shows the CSS Grid region, as shown by the inspector it is square in size
2. Shows the region formed by all the CSS tracks, we can see that total height of all the columns exceed the height of the actual grid
3. Row & Column tracks are sized by fractional spacing
4. Height & Width given to the CSS Grid (it is actually 60vmin). Here the computed values are shown. We see both are same, forming a square.
5. The computed values of the tracks are shown. Clearly we can see that width of column is **not** same as height of row. Moreover **grid-template-rows** details show that height of 2nd row is slightly larger than height of the other 2 rows.

I cannot understand why is this happening. I want to put a bar just below the Grid, but since the apparent height of the grid, exceeds the actual height, the element which should be below the grid gets overlapped with the grid.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.center-area {
  width: 60vmin;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.board {
  height: 60vmin;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .board {
    height: 90vmin;
  }
}

.cell-content-empty {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(1) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(2) {
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(4) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(5) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(6) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(7) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(8) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(9) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

```html
<div className="center-area">
<div class="board">
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example in a code snippet to your question?

Comment: please provide a the code to reproduce the issue

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: Added codesandbox sample. My original code is in ReactJS, so added a similar sample. Similar behavior can be observed in the sample. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement

```
.board {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

does not mean what you expect it to do

In the [standard definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#fr-unit) you can read

> 7.2.3. Flexible Lengths: the fr unit
>
> A flexible length or  is a dimension with the fr unit, which represents a fraction of the **leftover space** in the grid container. Tracks sized with fr units are called flexible tracks as they flex in response to leftover space similar to how flex items fill space in a flex container.

Bold text is mine. The space that is distributed evenly between cells is the remaining space. If there is no remianing space, the fr statement is useless. For your case, it will be better to set a percentage value

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.center-area {
  width: 60vmin;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.board {
  height: 60vmin;
  width: 60vmin;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 33.33%);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .board {
    height: 90vmin;
  }
}

.cell-content-empty {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(1) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(2) {
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(4) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(5) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(6) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(7) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(8) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}

.border-holder:nth-child(9) {
  border-top: 1px solid #808080;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

```html
<div className="center-area">
<div class="board">
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-holder">
    <div class="cell"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/c0q1Ew/transparent.png" alt="" class="cell-content-empty"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok! Setting the size to percentage works. I have 2 questions. I have specified the height of the grid container as 60vmin. Doesn't that create the required available space, which could have been distributed evenly? Also when we specify the size in percentage for tracks does it refers to size of the element itself or its parent? I am assuming the element itself.

Comment: In the original snippet, the width of the board was greater than the height. This made the inner images have a width than translated in the same height, since the images are squared, and this height was bigger than 1/3 of the board height. And yes, the percentages are referred to the element itself (the board)